# Is there a way to address all elements of JSON array when creating a constraint in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Does PostgreSQL provide any notation/method for putting a constraint on **each** element of a JSON array?

An example:

```
create table orders(data json);

insert into orders values ('
{
    "order_id": 45,
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id": 1,
            "name": "Book"
        },
        {
            "product_id": 2,
            "name": "Painting"
        }
    ]
}
');
```

I can easily add a constraint on the `order_id` field:

```
alter table orders add check ((data->>'order_id')::integer >= 1);
```

Now I need to do the same with `product_id`. I can put constraint on idividual array items:

```
alter table orders add check ((data->'products'->0->>'product_id')::integer >= 1);
alter table orders add check ((data->'products'->1->>'product_id')::integer >= 1);
-- etc.
```

So obviously what I'm looking for is some kind of wildcard operator for **matching any JSON array** element:

```
alter table orders add check ((data->'products'->*->>'product_id')::integer >= 1);
--                                               ^ like this
```

I know that this can be done by extracting products to a separate `products` table with a foreign key to `orders`. But I want to know if this is possible within single JSON column, so I can keep that in mind when designing a database schema.

Comment: I think you'd need a subquery to do this at the moment. I'd put my validation in a PL/PgSQL procedure that looped over each array element and use that in my CHECK constraint. Consider raising this use case on the mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I asked [this question on PostgreSQL mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACYP-QPiPfgGz6U_Q87p4fwkiFP9JOx6h9T0e4zsXZi8QD2wTA@mail.gmail.com), as [suggested by Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245997/is-there-a-way-to-address-all-elements-of-json-array-when-creating-a-constraint#comment32009083_21245997), and I've got the answer.

In short the solution is to write a procedure which materializes JSON array to PostgreSQL array:

```
create function data_product_ids(JSON) returns integer[] immutable  as $$
select array_agg((a->>'product_id')::integer) from
json_array_elements($1->'products') as a $$ language sql ;
```

and use that procedure in `CHECK` statment:

```
alter table orders add check (1 <= ALL(data_product_ids(data)));
```

For more details on how this works se [the answer on PostgreSQL mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAEF8rJtwAC7om=MLt2a03XQTgVL1cYhLypBHv69-ZWrixztG6g@mail.gmail.com). Credits to Joel Hoffman.

Answer (score 1):

From one of the developers of JSON for Postgres

> The path stuff does not support wildcards.