# Django JSONField and searching through the list of dictionaries using ILIKE

Tags: django

Is it possible to search against one key value in the list of dictionaries using ILIKE (icontains) operator? My json field looks like this:

```
object = MyModel()
object.json_data = [
    {
        "type": 1,
        "results": [
            {
                "score": 1,
                "comment": "Some text comment 1",
            },
            {
                "score": 2,
                "comment": "Some text comment 2",
            },
            {
                "score": 3,
                "comment": "Some text comment 3",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": 2,
        "results": [
            {
                "score": 4,
                "comment": "Some text comment 4",
            },
            {
                "score": 5,
                "comment": "Some text comment 5",
            },
            {
                "score": 6,
                "comment": "Some text comment 6",
            }
        ]
    }
]
object.save()
```

And now, how to write the query to search in a "comment" key?

```
MyModel.objects.filter(json_data__??__results__??__comment__icontains="text comment")
```

I'm using Django 1.9.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to write your own custom filter function to filter the results with a regular expression. What is the exact result that you need? queryset? list of matches?

Answer (score 19):

this works for me (note the `[]`)

```
query = User.objects.filter(data__campaigns__contains=[{'key': 'value'}])
```

Comment: This is a workable solution except requirement of case insensitive.

Comment: I can't believe the solution was easy like this.... Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to search simply by chaining it, django style:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(json_data__results__contains={"comment":"text comment"})
```

check out the documentation for JSON field in Django 1.9:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield

which includes `contains` lookup: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.contains

If this doesn't work for case-insensitive, then I would see what query it produces, and simply rework it with extra where:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["json_data->>'results'->'comment' ILIKE %s"], params=["%text comment%"])
```

or you can use the specific symbols for json as stated in postgres documentation, like `<@`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

Comment: The thing is that I can't filter over all items in the list. When I specify the index = "json_data__0__results__0__comment__contains='Text'" everything works, but how to filter over all items in the list?

Comment: That seems really weird, it should definitely go over all the list values. Here the writer demonstrates it works for him... http://orokusaki.posthaven.com/djangos-new-jsonfield-is-awesome

If something like `comment__contains='text'` doesn't work for you, then I suggest using the custom where, as I wrote in my answer. Or writing completely raw sql.

Comment: Nope. 

Works: `Select * from xxx WHERE json_data::jsonb->0->'results'->0->'comment' = '"Text"';` ***** 
Does not Work: `Select * from xxx WHERE json_data::jsonb->'results'->'comment' = '"Text"';`  *****
Works: `Select * from xxx WHERE json_data::jsonb #> ARRAY['0', 'results', '0', 'comment'] = '"Text"';`  *****
Does not Work: `Select * from xxx WHERE json_data::jsonb #> ARRAY['results', 'comment'] = '"Text"';`  *****
Does not Work: `Select * from xxx WHERE json_data::jsonb @> '{"comment": "Text"}'::jsonb;`  *****

So I have to specify list index each time, :-(

Comment: Hm, I really don't understand this behavior. Here is another user suggesting the same approach which seems to be working http://stackoverflow.com/a/19868697/3221452. I'm really clueless why it searches only with indexes for you. Do you have the proper column type in your database? Check directly in database.

Comment: Ok, there is no way to use a wilcard in the path -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245997/is-there-a-way-to-address-all-elements-of-json-array-when-creating-a-constraint/21267504#21267504 .. So I'm getting ready to play with `jsonb_populate_recordset`, `jsonb_array_elements` etc. Thanks for your help.